# Reference dll without version visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, version, assembly-binding-redirect

I have an application that is referencing a dll that will keep changing to a newer version (with backwards compatibility).

My app (built in visual studio 2015) will work with any version - the problem is - i need to reference the dll without specifying the version bec the latest version dll will constantly be replacing the dll in my project (office requirements) and i dont want to recompile my project every time the dll is updated

I tried the following:

1. setting   `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` in my .csproj file
2. ```
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += delegate (object s, ResolveEventArgs re)
   {
       AssemblyName theName = new AssemblyName(re.Name);

       if (theName.Name == "name, version, key")
       {
           return Assembly.LoadFile("name without version");
       }

       return null;
   };
   ```

im not really sure where to put the second thing that i tried but nothing seems to be working!!

Comment: Is the issue version numbering? Usually minor versions won't cause problems, major versions do. In the reference properties do you have the "Specific Version" setting set to false? Have you looked at doing binding redirects? Are you trying to have multiple copies of the DLL in the same directory at the same time?

Comment: No - its not minor versions - its a dll that is updated to a complete new version often. I tried setting specific version to false - that did not work. i read that that is for compile time only. 

not trying to have multiple copies of the dll - one dll thats constantly updated. please help!

Comment: Is that "a dll that will keep changing" strongly signed?

Comment: yes it is strongly signed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A neater way would be using the AssemblyResolve event -

Something like the following:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, argsAssembly) =>
            {
                if (argsAssembly.Name.StartsWith the name of your dll)
                    return Assembly.Load(load the dll);
                return null;
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it one way - but im still looking for a better answer -

i created a class from the assembly by loading my dll

like -

```
Assembly assemblyInstance=Assembly.Load(dll);
Type[] asseblyTypes=assemblyInstance.GetTypes();

foreach(Type t in asseblyTypes)
{
    if(t.fullName.Equals(name of class i want))
    {
        try to get the method info by t.GetMethod(name,type of parameter)
        and then do methodInfo.Invoke...
    }
}
```

works... but id like a better answer